# Putting simple_html_dom variables into an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, simple-html-dom

I am trying to extract some info from a website using simple_html_dom.

Currently I am using:

```
foreach ($html->find('div.product') as $results) {
    foreach ($results->find('div.image') as $img) {
        echo $img;
    }
    foreach ($results->find('a.title') as $title) {
        echo $title->plaintext;
    }
    foreach ($results->find('div.price') as $price) {
        echo $price;
    }
}
```

Which works fine. However I need to be able to echo each variable outside of the foreach loop. If I do that using the above code, only the final result will be displayed, i.e. out of the 10 products I am trying to extract only the 10th will be displayed.

Is there a way I can use an array to store all the results from each foreach loop then echo them out once the overall loop is finished?

Something like this:

```
foreach ($html->find('div.product') as $results) {
    foreach ($results->find('div.image') as $img) {
        array($img);
    }
    foreach ($results->find('a.title') as $title) {
        array($title->plaintext);
    }
    foreach ($results->find('div.price') as $price) {
        array($price);
    }
}
echo array($img);
echo array($title);
echo array($price);
```

Sorry if this question is confusing I don't have the best grasp on PHP, especially arrays!

Comment: please provide some sample html to be parsed

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/arrays

Comment: and you do realize that `$results->find` already returns arrays, right?

Comment: I was using this: $html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hat&x=0&y=0');

Comment: No sorry I did not. I've never worked with PHP before at this level, so apologise if the question came across as stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array_img = array();
$array_title = array();
$array_price = array();
foreach ($html->find('div.product') as $results) {
    foreach ($results->find('div.image') as $img) {
        $array_img[] = $img;
    }
    foreach ($results->find('a.title') as $title) {
        $array_title[]= $title->plaintext;
    }
    foreach ($results->find('div.price') as $price) {
        $array_price[]= $price;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_img);
print_r($array_title);
print_r($array_price);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can see the data I want using this option, however it returns hundreds of lines of code around it. Is there anyway to only extract the specific info.

Comment: If it helps I am using this html: $html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hat&x=0&y=0');

Comment: When I used the first block of code in my question I would get the actual image of the product, the title, and the price. However when I use print_r($array_img) I get a lot of unwanted lines of code

Comment: you have to use keys for echo specific info that you want to use like `$array_price[0]` check out the arrays manuel from php.net [php: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$images = array();
foreach ($html->find('div.product') as $results) {
    foreach ($results->find('div.image') as $img) {
        $images[] = $img; // append $img to the $images array
    }
}

var_dump($images);
```

Do the same for the title and price data as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This outputs hundreds of lines of code similar to this "array(15) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#653 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=> string(3) "div"" Is there a way to only display the images? Thank a lot.

Comment: What images? Your find() isn't looking images, it's looking for divs with css class "image".

Comment: Also if it helps, this is the html I am using: $html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hat&x=0&y=0');

Comment: Yes I know, it looks for that div then pulls out whatever is in that div which is the actual image in this case.

Comment: Unless you've got more than the code you've shown above, then no, it doesn't pull out images. It's only looking for `<div class="image">` and returning the matching DOM nodes.

Comment: It is displaying images when I echo $img. The image thing isn't that big of a deal, all I wanted to do was be able to echo out each different variable outside of the main foreach loop, which your code does, however it returns a lot of lines of code I don't want. If you give me a few minutes and you don't mind I can upload what I have now to a server to show you what I am seeing?

Comment: That's from the var_dump, which is was just to dump out what's in the array. The actual display code is up to you to add in. However, note that since you're fetchign divs from the original tree, you're actually outputting stuff like `<div class="image"><img src="..."></div>`, and not just "images".

Comment: Ok that explains it, I will have a go at doing that. Apologies for taking up your time and thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$img = array();
$title = array();
$price = array();
foreach ($html->find('div.product') as $results) {
    $img[] = $results->find('div.image');
    $title[] = $results->find('a.title');
    $price[] = $results->find('div.price');
}

print_r($img);
print_r($title);
print_r($price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand you question, try the following.

```
$priceList = $titleList = $imgList = array();

foreach ($html->find('div.product') as $results) {<br/>
    foreach ($results->find('div.image') as $img) {<br/>
        $imgList[] = $img;<br/>
    }<br/>
    foreach ($results->find('a.title') as $title) {<br/>
        titleList[] = $title;<br/>
    }<br/>
    foreach ($results->find('div.price') as $price) {<br/>
        priceList[] = $price;<br/>
    }<br/>
}<br/>
foreach ($imgList as $img) {<br/>
        echo $img;<br/>
}<br/>
```

And so on...